# How can I get someone else in Minecraft Comes Alive to get a divorce?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

In my modded survival world, I wanted my NPC son to marry some random woman, but it turned out that the woman was married. I'm too lazy to go get another woman/kill the husband, so is there any way I can get the woman to divorce her husband?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way except if you install a mod or something but I think the only option here is to kill the husband as no other opportunity is there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Arqade! I've noticed you've been posting a lot of answers that are not being well-received, due to their lack of evidence and/or inherent uncertainty. You may want to take a look at the [site's tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how we operate and the quality expected of posts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. I think the only way to romance someone already married is to kill their spouse. Don't kill the spouse in front of the person you want to romance, it might end badly because they scream at you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. The thing is i haven't done something like this but, Try gifting the woman and their spouse divorce papers. It may work.

Comment: Speculative answers typically are not very well received.

Answer (score 0):

In the mod there are divorce papers, you can use them to divorce your own spouse or divorce another. just simply give them the papers and they're immediately single.